# Specify aws named profile S3Boto3Storage

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am using [S3Boto3Storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) for uploading django images to s3. I have multiple profiles in my local. Can I specify profile name with S3Boto3Storage ?

Comment: what do you mean profile?

Comment: hey @ruddra I meant `named profile` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, this isn't exposed in this way yet, but I do think it's something we should add. Here are a couple of workarounds that work right now:

Set the BOTO_DEFAULT_PROFILE environment variable to the name of the profile. Docs for env vars

Use your own Botocore session:

import botocore.session

import boto3

## Set your profile name on a low-level Botocore session

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
session.profile = 'my-profile-name'
```

## Tell Boto 3 to use that session by default

```
boto3.setup_default_session(botocore_session=session)
```